# Android: Authenticating requests to OpenAI

Tags: java, android

I wanted to make an app that allows chatting by putting in the ChatGPT API key, but it comes out like a picture and I'm curious about the solution.

Note, that I'm still a beginner.

Here is the error response:

[image]

Below is the code.

```
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(jsonBody.toString(),JSON);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                // url은  https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions/object Create completion 참조
                .url("https://api.openai.com/v1/completions")
                // header은 sk- 부터 api 코드
                .header("Txt","Bearer apt-key")
                .post(body)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull IOException e) {
                addResopnse("Failed to load reponse duo to"+e.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull Response response) throws IOException {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                    try {
                        jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().toString());
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("choices");
                        String result = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("text");
                        addResopnse(result.trim());
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }else {
                    addResopnse("Failed to load reponse duo to"+response.body().string());
                }
```

Comment: You need to provide an api key as Bearer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide key along with your API's end point. You can do like this.

```
@Headers(
    "accept:application/json",
    "Authorization:Bearer YOUR_KEY"
)
API END-POINT
```